# How to use the DATETIME type for a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, variables, types

What I want to do is make a variable `date_arrived` that stores a date and time value when a **Client** makes a **Reservation** for a hotel room. Then, I want to `Insert into` the table a date and time value. The only way I can think of doing this is like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Reservation
(
    id_reservation SMALLINT IDENTITY(1 ,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    date_arrived DATETIME NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Reservation 
VALUES ( ??? );
```

But I've seen people use the `DATETIME` type with `@datetime` syntax but I don't understand this and don't know if it will work with my example. I know using `varchar(n)` is not convenient. So what is the best way to register a date and time values into a variable?

Comment: It is recommend to **always** explicitly specify the **columns** you're inserting into: `INSERT INTO Reservation  (date_arrived) VALUES ('2021-03-21');`

Comment: thanks this seems helpful i'll try it out

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.  All databases differ from each other, and each seems to take particular pride in having their own date/time functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing what you're asking for, it sounds like what you need is along the lines of:

(You haven't tagged your database but it looks like SQL Server syntax)

```
CREATE TABLE Reservation
(
    Reservation_Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1 ,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Booking_Date DATETIME NOT NULL default (GETDATE()),
    Arrival_Date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Duration TINYINT NOT NULL default(1),
    Checkout_Date as DATEADD (day, Duration, Arrival_date)
)
```

- `Reservation_Id` will link you to your other data for the reservation eg guests.
- `Booking_Date` is "right now" when you insert the data, ie are making the booking, the date on which they booked - this is automatically populated
- `Arrival_Date` is the date/time they are due to arrive/room reserved for etc, you populate this
- `Duration` - how many days/nights etc
- `Checkout_Date` - you don't fill this in, it's caclulated from the Arrival_Date + Duration

You would insert data, assuming your values are passed as two variables,

```
insert into Reservation (Arrival_Date, Duration)
values (@ArrivalDate, @Duration)
select SCOPE_IDENTITY() --< returns the Reservation_Id for use elsewhere.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can insert value as:

```
Insert into reservation values(now());
```

Comment: what is "now()" in "values(now())" ? I don't have to manually insert different dates and times myself like this : Insert into reservation values('mm', 'dd', 'yy'); or something like that?

Comment: This is a SQL function and this function automatcally insert current date and time when user click on it. eg: '2018-11-23 17:31:26'

Comment: Thats MySQL only

Answer (score -2):

In MySQL you can use `now()` for inserting values in your table.

This can be taken care of by the database as well here is a syntax for this.

```
CREATE TABLE Reservation(id_reservation SMALLINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    date_arrived DATETIME Default now() NOT NULL)
```

Here is an example to fill values explicitly.

```
INSERT INTO reservation (id_reservation,date_arrived) VALUES (678,'2020-11-10 11:26:27');
```

Comment: Nice this seems like what I am looking for. But what is "now()" exactly and why do you have to use it? Because usually I insert values without typing "now()".

Comment: If you use the table creation syntax the way I have placed it. Then at the time of inserting values, you don't even need to insert the value for now(). Consider now() as an inbuilt fxn that provides you the current date and time in the specified format. Only this much will get your work done. ```INSERT INTO reservation (id_reservation) VALUES (678);

Comment: Ahh okay I see. I don't think I'll need it since when a client books for a hotel room, he will choose the date and time for the nights he is going to stay in that hotel, and not the date and time when he booked a room.

Comment: Thats MySQL only

Comment: @DaleK Yes, You are right I have used this only in MySql for avoiding any ambiguity I have added this to the answer part as well. Thanks.